# Rails 3: Delayed jobs, method 'delay' not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have delayed_job installed as a Gem and in my Gemfile. However, when I try to use delay in my controller as:

```
def send_warn_admin_email
    UserMailer.delay.warn_admin_email(self).deliver
  end
```

I get: `undefined method`delay' for UserMailer:Class`

What can cause this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry to ask, but are you sure you installed your bundle?

Comment: In the Rails console, try entering `Delayed` and press enter. Does it complain about a missing constant?

Comment: @Jack, yes I did run bundle install. @Brian, no, no erorr..

Comment: It seems that I do not have a table delayed_jobs, even tough the migration runs ok. ?

Comment: That code also looks suspicious. I'd assume you'd want to have the `.deliver` call be async, not the creation of the email. Does `UserMail.warn_admin_email(self).delay.deliver` work?

Comment: @Brian, no, it does not work. Same error. I can see the worker running on my rake jobs:work

Comment: Well, you could always try using [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Documentation.

> ```
> Due to how mailers are implemented in Rails 3, we had to do a little work
> ```
>
> around to get delayed_job to work.
>
> ```
> # without delayed_job
> Notifier.signup(@user).deliver
>
> # with delayed_job
> Notifier.delay.signup(@user)
>
>
> Remove the @.deliver@ method to make it work. It's not ideal, but it's
> ```
>
> the best we could do for now.

Bye